# Performclick does not function with android fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a problem with android studio. I use a fragment with a **bottomNavigationView**. It works fine if you click on the **bottomNavigation**. But if you simulate a click on the **bottomNavigation** it works for the first time and at the second time if you simulate the **performclick** again, it does not work.

I used also `view.callOnClick();` and for the fragment add and remove fragment, but both do not function for my problem. I really appreciate it, if anyone can solve my problem.

Here is the Code:

```
`
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    
   private Button send_order_button;
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstaceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public  void onStart() {
        send_order_button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.auftrag_abschicken);
    }

    send_order_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ProfilActivity pa = new ProfilActivity();
                  pa.changeFragment();
                  getActivity().finishActivity(ProfilActivity.class.hashCode());
    }
}`




`
public class ProfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ProfilActivity() {}

    public static Fragment selectedFragment = null;
    public static BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil);
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_chat);
        view.performClick();
    }

    public void changeFragment() {
       // bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_store);
        View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_store);
        view.performClick();
    }

    public BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_user :
                            selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_chat :
                            selectedFragment = new MailFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_store:
                            selectedFragment = new ShopFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    try {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
                        selectedFragment, "fragment").commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    };
                    return true;
                }
    };
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the default selected item in the `BottomNavigationView`. Why not just use `bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_store);` ?

Comment: I also tried it but it does not function with it, that was the reason why i used bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_store) as a  comment, to show that it also does not function. thank you for your answer